# XML Schema: Elements in any order and occurring 0-1 times or 0-* times

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I am working on an XML Schema (`message.xsd`) describing the structure of a message.

Here are the expected children of the `<message>` element (the root):

- `<from>`: Contains the address of the sender. Occurs 0 or 1 times.
- `<to>`: Contains the address of the recipient. Occurs 0 or more times.
- `<cc>`: Contains the address of the recipient in copy. Occurs 0 or more times.
- `<subject>`: Contains the subject of the message. Occurs 0 or 1 times.
- `<body>`: Contains the body of the message. Occurs 0 or 1 times.

The order of elements does not matter, it means that they can be in any order.

Here is a first simple XML example (`message-1.xml`) that has to be valid:

```
$ xmllint --schema message.xsd message-1.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message xmlns="http://yugiohjcj.1s.fr/message">
    <from>me@domain.com</from>
    <to>you@domain.com</to>
    <subject>How are you?</subject>
    <body>Hello. How are you? Thank you. Best regards.</body>
</message>
message-1.xml validates
```

And it is valid!

Here is a second more complex XML example (`message-2.xml`) that has to be valid:

```
$ xmllint --schema message.xsd message-2.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message xmlns="http://yugiohjcj.1s.fr/message">
    <subject>How are you?</subject>
    <body>Hello. How are you? Thank you. Best regards.</body>
    <from>me@domain.com</from>
    <to>you@domain.com</to>
    <to>and-you@domain.com</to>
    <cc>someone-else@domain.com</cc>
    <cc>again-someone-else@domain.com</cc>
</message>
message-2.xml validates
```

And it is valid!

Here is a third XML example (`message-3.xml`) that has to be not valid:

```
$ xmllint --schema message.xsd message-3.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message xmlns="http://yugiohjcj.1s.fr/message">
    <from>me@domain.com</from>
    <from>someone-else@domain.com</from>
    <to>you@domain.com</to>
    <subject>How are you?</subject>
    <subject>How are you again?</subject>
    <body>Hello. How are you? Thank you. Best regards.</body>
    <body>Hello. How are you again? Thank you. Best regards.</body>
</message>
message-3.xml validates
```

But it is valid!
That's the problem.

Here is my XML Schema (`message.xsd`):

```
$ cat message.xsd 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://yugiohjcj.1s.fr/message" targetNamespace="http://yugiohjcj.1s.fr/message" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="message">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="from"/>
                    <xs:element name="to"/>
                    <xs:element name="cc"/>
                    <xs:element name="subject"/>
                    <xs:element name="body"/>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I guess that I need to set the `maxOccurs` attribute to the value `1` somewhere or maybe I need to combine differently the `<xs:sequence>` and `<xs:choice>` elements but I have not found how to reach my goal.

Any idea how to fix this XML Schema please?

Thank you.

Best regards.

---

Edit: OK I found a workaround to my problem by using [Relax NG](http://relaxng.org/) instead of [XSD 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/). It works fine and it is compatible with [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).

Here is my `message.rng` file:

```
$ cat message.rng 
<element name="message" xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0">
    <interleave>
        <zeroOrMore>
            <element name="from">
                <text/>
            </element>
        </zeroOrMore>
        <zeroOrMore>
            <element name="to">
                <text/>
            </element>
        </zeroOrMore>
        <zeroOrMore>
            <element name="cc">
                <text/>
            </element>
        </zeroOrMore>
        <optional>
            <element name="subject">
                <text/>
            </element>
        </optional>
        <optional>
            <element name="body">
                <text/>
            </element>
        </optional>
    </interleave>
</element>
```

And here is the result on my 3 XML examples (`message-1.xml`, `message-2.xml` and `message-3.xml`):

```
$ xmllint --relaxng message.rng message-1.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message>
    <from>me@domain.com</from>
    <to>you@domain.com</to>
    <subject>How are you?</subject>
    <body>Hello. How are you? Thank you. Best regards.</body>
</message>
message-1.xml validates
$ xmllint --relaxng message.rng message-2.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message>
    <subject>How are you?</subject>
    <body>Hello. How are you? Thank you. Best regards.</body>
    <from>me@domain.com</from>
    <to>you@domain.com</to>
    <to>and-you@domain.com</to>
    <cc>someone-else@domain.com</cc>
    <cc>again-someone-else@domain.com</cc>
</message>
message-2.xml validates
$ xmllint --relaxng message.rng message-3.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message>
    <from>me@domain.com</from>
    <from>someone-else@domain.com</from>
    <to>you@domain.com</to>
    <subject>How are you?</subject>
    <subject>How are you again?</subject>
    <body>Hello. How are you? Thank you. Best regards.</body>
    <body>Hello. How are you again? Thank you. Best regards.</body>
</message>
Relax-NG validity error : Extra element subject in interleave
message-3.xml:7: element subject: Relax-NG validity error : Element message failed to validate content
message-3.xml fails to validate
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSD 1.0 if you want to allow elements to appear in any order then the only way to control how often each element may appear is using xs:all, and this constrains the number of appearances to be zero or one. So you can't achieve what you are attempting.

This restriction is lifted in XSD 1.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have an XSD 1.1 validator. I am using [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) in C that is only supporting XSD 1.0. I see that [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi) supports XSD 1.1 but in a beta version and [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) supports XSD1.1 only in a commercial version.

Comment: I sympathise. You get what you pay for.